# Joi, convert empty string to null

Tags: node.js, joi

I have the following rule: `Joi.string().empty("").default(null)`.

I assumed this rule would convert an empty string `""` to null, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

How do I get the desired behavior?

Answer (score 6):

There's a slight difference if the rule is to be applied to a non-required field.

Using `empty("")`: if a request provides `""` as the value, it will be replaced with `undefined`.

Using `default(null)`: means if the value is `undefined` it will be replaced with `null` - note that if no value is provided at all in the request it will also be `undefined`.

So your example will accept any strings, but if the value is `""` it will be replaced with `undefined`, and then if the value is `undefined` it will be replaced with `null`.

Therefore the value will always be `null` for *every* request, unless a string other than `""` is provided.

If you want the value to remain `undefined` when no value was provided by the request, you need something like:

```
Joi.alternatives()
  .try(
    Joi.string().valid('').empty('').default(null), // accept only empty strings and convert those to null
    Joi.string() // accept every other string
  )
```

With this, if the request value is a string it'll be accepted, unless it's `""` then it will be converted to `null`. Otherwise, if the request did not provide any value for the field, the value will remain `undefined`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see what's wrong. I get the desired behavior from the provided schema:

```
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');

const joiSchema = Joi.string().empty('').default(null);

const { error, value } = joiSchema.validate();
console.log(`error: ${error}`, `value: ${value}`);
```

Outputs:

```
"error: undefined"
"value: null"
```

Make sure you are using the latest version. Check the working code at RunKit: https://runkit.com/rvypandey/5e387545896365001a90a87b

Comment: This snippet validates nothing at all, but the question specifies desired behaviour for validating an empty string `""`

Comment: The header of the question itself specifies conversion - `Joi, convert empty string to null`.
Also, the description says the same.

I have provided the snippet to validate + convert (using default)